# mvim --version shows +lua/dyn but echo has("lua") returns 0

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, neocomplete

```
mvim --version
```

shows

```
+lua/dyn
```

but on mvim commandline

```
echo has("lua")
```

returns 0. neocomplete plugin is not working because of this.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall and reinstall solved the problem.

```
brew uninstall --force macvim
brew install macvim --with-lua --override-system-vim
```